# Is checkedness a word?

Tags: programming

In the W3C HTML 5 specification, there are a number times the word `checkedness` is used, the following is where each word links to when used:

> [Form controls have a value and a checkedness.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-checked)

Is `checkedness` a technical term or a word defined in a dictionary as I'm unable to find it in both UK and US dictionaries and I'm unsure of what it means?

If it is a word can a definition be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A checkbox is *checked* or *unchecked*, and the *-ness* suffix is *productive*, meaning that it can be added freely to a word (in this case, a participle) to denote a state or quality. So they’ve coined *checkedness* as a technical term simply to mean “the state of being checked or unchecked”.

You probably wouldn’t find it in a dictionary, but it makes just as much sense as more common *-edness* terms—for example, *handedness*, the state of being left- or right-handed.

Comment: (1) Even if 'productive' did mean 'can be added freely to a word', you should give supporting evidence. But (2) 'productive' is gradable: 'The suffix -ese is less productive than the suffix -less ...' {[Understanding Morphology_Martin Haspelmath, Andrea Sims p117](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gWnYAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=suffix+%22less+productive%22&source=bl&ots=8D_TLmR6ZW&sig=-YA4ciNMiIrdddiKHwlPQmDmO0M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV08_owdTNAhWpK8AKHeMoC3gQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=suffix%20%22less%20productive%22&f=false)}...

Comment: , meaning that 'even though the suffix -ese _is_ productive, it can't just be added at will to any word to give an automatically acceptable new word'.